# Unable to get the popup open in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik

So, I am trying to create a calendar popup that opens as soon as the textbox get focus. Below is the code I am using.

```
                            <TextBox x:Name="CalendarTextBox" BorderBrush="#CCCCCCCC" Foreground="#FF777777" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="305" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="10" Margin="0,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionBrush="#FF0081A7" BorderThickness="2" GotFocus="CalendarTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="CalendarTextBox_LostFocus"/>
                        <Popup x:Name="PopUpCalendar" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=CalendarTextBox}" StaysOpen="False" Width="305" Height="305" Panel.ZIndex="200">
                            <telerik:RadCalendar HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical" AreWeekNamesVisible="False" Width="305" Height="305">
                                <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                    <telerik:Windows8Theme/>
                                </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                            </telerik:RadCalendar>
                        </Popup>
```

Code behind:

```
    Private Sub CalendarTextBox_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    PopUpCalendar.IsOpen = True
End Sub

Private Sub CalendarTextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    PopUpCalendar.IsOpen = False
End Sub
```

The similar code works well for other popup in page. But somehow calendar doesn't show at all. Weird thing is, code is executed properly, but after that, there is no calendar popup on page. I am unable to figure out what I missed. I have even increased Zindex to a very high number.

Comment: When you say "code is executed properly" do you mean that the `Popup` opens, but the `RadCalendar` is not visible? Or does the `Popup` not even open?

Comment: Popup is not opening. I put a breakpoint in the code, and the code ran.

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint in `CalendarTextBox_LostFocus` and see if that is getting ran immediately after the popup is opening? If the popup receives focus when it's opened, perhaps the `LostFocus` event is fired, causing the popup to immediately close.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out stays open property was causing problems. I set that to true and it worked. Now both events fire as expected.